# Wpftoolkit dragging messagebox control with flowdirection="righttoleft" issue

Tags: wpf, messagebox

I need a styled messagebox with right to left text direction for wpf application

I am using wpftoolkit 4.1 messagebox control by xceed.
Setting fllowdirection="RightToLeft" works fine for setting the text direction but dragging the window is a big problem, the window is being dragged quickly to the other side and disappears so only killing the process works from that point

any ideas?

Comment: You only see that when you set flowdirection? That sounds like a bug, I would report it to them.

Comment: I already did. Thanks